# Ansible - how to register output from "FIND" module and use in other

Tags: ansible

I need to find a files in unknown directory place and remove them.
Tried to use "find" module, register its output, and pass it to "file".

Even if I see path registered, I can not use it later:

```
< TASK [print find_result] >
ok: [1.2.3.4] => {
    "find_result": {
        "changed": false, 
        "examined": 3119, 
        "files": [
            {
                "atime": 1483973253.7295375, 
           ...
                "mode": "0600", 
                "mtime": 1483973253.7295375, 
                "nlink": 1, 
                "path": "/tmp/delme",
```

My playbook is:

```
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  become: no
  vars:
    find_what: "delme*"
    find_where: "/tmp"

  tasks:
  - name: finding files
    find:
      paths:            "{{ find_where }}"
      patterns:         "{{ find_what }}"
      recurse:          "yes"
      file_type:        "file"
    register: find_result

# \/ for debugging
  - name: print find_result
    debug: var=find_result

  - name: remove files
    file:
        path= "{{ item.path }}"
        state=absent
    with_items: "{{ find_result.files }}"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a syntax flaw in `file` task – space after `=`.

Try:

```
- name: remove files
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ find_result.files }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error at your *remove files* task.

You can use:

```
- name: remove files
  file: >
    path={{ item.path }}
    state=absent
  with_items: "{{ find_result.files }}"
```

Or

```
- name: remove files
  file: path={{ item.path }} state=absent
  with_items: "{{ find_result.files }}"
```